# Does calling a method from within the same method create a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory

```
-(void)doSomething 
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Will this cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

(This is called recursion; when a method calls itself. EDIT: Apparently not, according to the discussion below.)

A memory leak occurs when a reference to an object in memory is removed, but the object remains in memory. As long as you are properly releasing allocated memory, a memory leak will not occur.

Comment: Yes, but this actually isn't recursion, because it defers the next call to a timer.

Comment: @jtbandes: That could be argued. In my eyes, the method basically waits to call itself again, which is still recursion.

Comment: @jtbandes: Say you removed the timer (`afterDelay:`) and used a variation of `sleep` to perform the delay. In both situations, the final result is the method calling itself.

Comment: Your eyes deceive you. When the method is called for the second time, the backtrace will not include the first call, but rather the timer-fire event. Feel free to verify this in the debugger.

Comment: @jtbandes: I understand what happens behind the scenes, but no matter how you slice it, the method will end up calling itself again, albeit via a different route.

Comment: The method will end up *being called* again, but no, using a timer is NOT recursion. You won't be able to overflow the stack this way.

Comment: @jtbandes: Okay, so it's *indirect* recursion.

Comment: Nope -- it is not recursion.  Not in any way.   Recursion occurs when a method/function calls itself and returns through itself (though a tail call optimization may be used to make the return more efficient). Since this is neither the method calling itself, nor caller returning through the calling method, this is *not recursion*.  *Indirect recursion* would be if A calls B calls C calls A calls B calls A calls C calls A, etc.... but there is still a return path and deep stack.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't leak. self is retained while the method is getting called, then released when the invokation finishes.

This is not a good way to create a timer, though. Use NSTimer instead: it is much more accurate and won't drift like this will.